# menuPortalTarget doesn't not work if react-select dropdown opens inside modal

Tags: react-select

I have a problem react-select dropdown opens inside modal

Below is my coding:

```html
<Select                
styles={{
  menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })
}}
options={optionsHour}
value={{ label: durationHour, value: durationHour }}
onChange={(e) => { setDurationHour(e.value) }}
>
</Select>
```

This one is the current result, it cannot show react_select dropdown over modal.

[image: img1]

I tried the below code with using `menuPortalTarget`, but it also cannot work.

```html
<Select                
styles={{
  menu: provided => ({ ...provided, zIndex: 9999 })
}}
menuPortalTarget={document.body}
options={optionsHour}
value={{ label: durationHour, value: durationHour }}
onChange={(e) => { setDurationHour(e.value) }}
>
</Select>
```

Below result is what I've tried:

[image: img2]

Actually, I want the result like below the picture:

[image: img3]

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: What html element is your modal made from? If it's a `<dialog>` element, then you won't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Give your modal a class (for example, `dialog-base`) and then reference it in `menuPortalTarget`:

```
  menuPortalTarget={document.getElementsByClassName('dialog-base')[0] as HTMLElement}
```

Then add the following prop as well:

```
  menuPosition="fixed"
```